# How can I select the inserted values in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am working with a stored procedure that inserts values in a table: an ID and the current Date. I know how to get the last used ID with `SCOPE_IDENTITY` but I also need to `SELECT` the Date that was just inserted. Any ideas?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertOrderHeader]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO OrderHeaders (OrderStateId,DateTime) VALUES (1,GETDATE()); 
    SELECT CONVERT(int, SCOPE_IDENTITY()) Id
END
```

Comment: OUTPUT-clause https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-output-clause-for-insert-and-delete-statements

Comment: or just add GETDATE() to your last select statement? Though unlikely in this scenario, you might want to assign GETDATE to a variable so your code uses the exact same value for every statement within your procedure. Then you would just add that variable to your select statement instead of the function call.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I've got the stored procedures already written and there is a bunch of them already prefixed with sp_, but thanks for the heads up... so many rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause for this:

```
INSERT INTO OrderHeaders (OrderStateId,DateTime) 
OUTPUT inserted.OrderStateId,inserted.DateTime
VALUES (1,GETDATE());
```

The `OUTPUT` clause is used to return the modified values in all the data modification statements, ie INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, MERGE. Like triggers, the new values are accessed through the `inserted` pseudo-table while the deleted/overwritten values through the `deleted` table